# OpenNI and OpenCV

Tags: opencv, openni, simple-openni

I am implementing an algorithm for finger detection using OpenNI and OpenCv 2.4 and Kinect.
The problem is I don't know how to get started, I found a piece of code and trying to run it.
But the problem is imgproc_c.h has alot of errors as (undeclared CvMoments,CvDistanceFunction) and many others of this type.

I checked and made sure of the header files, I even compared it with the code online of imgproc_c.h and it's exactly the same.

I have a feeling that openCV 2.4 is not functioning correctly in my case,
Any clue ?

Comment: You should post your code and errors

Comment: A good tutorial about C++ programming seems to help you. The errors you write about are more about not knowing how to make a C++ project than about OpenCV.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know where to start I sugest you start reading "Computer Vision" from Ballard and Brown, old but gold, it's free: http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/BOOKS/BANDB/bandb.htm

I can assure you that there are several ways to make a finger detection, but never one really simple.

Comment: https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/modules/imgproc/include/opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h?rev=3061

Comment: @MikrolDel  I am using windows and I don't have #include <CLNUIDevice.h> 
CL NUI SDK thing, as I am running this code and it needs the header ''CLNUIDevice.h". 
I simply added this file but I get an error  'CreateNUICamera' : function does not take 0 arguments. Is it  CL NUI SDK works with openNI in the first place ? because I am using OpenNI.

Comment: @ MikroDel The code I am using is under this video ...the first code       http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lCuItHQEgEQ&feature=player_embedded#!

Comment: Hi I realized the reason it's that I didn't include #include "opencv2\opencv.hpp"...just in-case anyone faces this problem that's the reason ... cheers :)

Comment: @shereen You should post this as the answer to your question and then mark it as the accepted answer to better help anyone who finds this thread later.